# How to get out of onmousemove event?

Tags: javascript, html

I am dynamically creating a table, with a set number of rows and columns. Once you fire the `onmousedown` event, it will run a loop to find out which `<td></td>` you *pressed* and are *moving over*, and set it's background color to red.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utQsM/1/)**

I just don't understand how to stop the background color changing once you have fired the `onmouseup` event.

This is the code part that I am stuck on:

```
function mousedown() {
    var elements = document.querySelector('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].onmousemove = function() {
            this.style.background = "red";
        }
        elements[i].onmouseup = function() {
            this.style.background = "none";
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `onmousemove` handlers?

Comment: @cookiemonster once the user has fired the onmouseup event, stop coloring the table cells red.

Comment: Yes, I know. Remove the handlers. Use a loop to assign them  `null`.

Comment: Also, `document.querySelector('table').getElementsByTagName('td')` can be written as `document.querySelectorAll('table td')`

Comment: @cookiemonster Could you please provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Inside your `mouseup` handler, just do another loop like you did when you assigned the handlers, but instead use `elements[i].onmousemove = null`

Comment: @cookiemonster, doesn't work in the way that the colored squares are overwritten back to null if you hover over them.

Comment: I don't know what that has to do with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a flag:

```
var flag = false;
function mousedown() {
    flag = true;
    var elements = document.querySelector('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].onmousemove = function() {
            if (flag) this.style.background = "red";
        }
        elements[i].onmouseup = function() {
            flag = false;
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baacke/utQsM/3/)** here.

I added:

```
function mouseup() {
        var elements = document.querySelector('table').getElementsByTagName('td');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].onmousemove = null;
        }
    }
```

and

```
table.onmouseup = mouseup;
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different approach: http://jsfiddle.net/QYg28/

```
(function() {
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var table = document.createElement('table');

    function createTable(rows, columns) {
        var tr;
        var td;
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            table.appendChild(tr);
            for (var j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                td = document.createElement('td');
                td.onmouseover = function(){ 
                    if(mouseDown)
                        this.style.background = "red";
                }
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
        body.appendChild(table);
    }

    mouseDown = false;

    function mousedown() {
        mouseDown = true;
    }

    function mouseup(){
        mouseDown = false;
    }

    window.onload = createTable(25, 25);
    table.onmousedown = mousedown;
    table.onmouseup = mouseup;
})();
```